# Return multiple values using asynctask

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am trying to return multiple rows from my database. I have two coordinates that I want to retrieve that are stored in my database, namely Longitude and Latitude. As my asynctask currently only can return a row. How should I change my code so it is able to return multiple rows from the database?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Below are my codes:

php codes

```
 $user=$_POST["username"];

  $query = "SELECT longitude,latitude FROM friends INNER JOIN coordinates ON friends.username = coordinates.username WHERE friends.friend_of='$user'";
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (!$sql) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)>0){
    $response["longitude"] = $row[0];
    $response["latitude"] = $row[1];
    die(json_encode($response));
    }
```

Asynctask class.

```
class Findfriends extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", args[0]);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    GET_FRIENDS, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Borrower_AP.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                Longitude = json.getDouble("longitude");
                Latitude = json.getDouble("latitude");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply return a list of elements you want to return.

Comment: Simply create an Model to keep data you want to return.

Comment: You can return jsonarray or return list of your rows

Comment: @KishuDroid Is there any examples on how to do it?

Comment: @IngoSchwarz any further explanation?

Comment: You can write one function which will return array and use while loop to the size of that array. In while loop add your elements in array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to mistakes here, the first one is that your PHP code is Just returning one row, instead you have to use something like this:

```
 $user=$_POST["username"];

  $query = "SELECT longitude,latitude FROM friends INNER JOIN coordinates ON friends.username = coordinates.username WHERE friends.friend_of='$user'";
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (!$sql) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

On the other hand in your Android code, and if you are using Google Maps Api, you can return an ArrayList, something like this:

```
class Findfriends extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<LatLong> {

  protected ArrayList<LatLong> doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
    ArrayList<LatLong> geoPos=new ArrayList<LatLong>();
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", args[0]);
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    GET_FRIENDS, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                //Complete here the code in which you iterate over the json and add each point to your ArrayList<LatLong>
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return geoPos;
    }


}
```

Comment: Think I need to change my parser too right? Cause I am using a JSONParser to process the data and I am not too sure how to change it to return an array

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the php script like this,

```
$query = "SELECT longitude,latitude FROM friends INNER JOIN coordinates ON friends.username = coordinates.username WHERE friends.friend_of='$user'";
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)
   {
   $latlongArray =array();
   $latlongArray ["longitude"] = $row[0];
   $latlongArray ["latitude"] = $row[1];
   array_push($response["DATA"],$latlongArray) 
   }
$response["success"] = "1";
echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{ 
 $response["success"] = "0";
 echo json_encode($response);
}
```

And in android code, in Post execute paste this code, in logcat you will see the lat / longs from the database.

```
 JSONArray ja = json.getJSONArray("DATA");
 for (int r = 0; r < ja.length(); r++) {
 JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(r);
 Log.i("Lat / Long",obj.getString("latitude")+" , "+obj.getString("longitude"));
 }
```

Try this it may help you.. And it is working code. 
Thank you,

Comment: <br /><b>Warning</b>:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>/home/u524163630/public_html/check_if_friends.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />{"DATA":null,"success":"1"}. I got this error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own handler like this:

```
//import android.os.Handler; this import is required.
public class MyHandler extends Handler{

   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       super.handleMessage(msg);
       List<YourObject> objs=(List<YourObject>)msg.obj;     
   }

}
```

In your activity create async object as follows:

```
MyDataFetcher mdf=new MyDataFetcher(new MyHandler());
```

Write your Async like this:

```
class MyDataFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private Handler handler
    public MyDataFetcher(Handler handler){
        this.handler=handler;
    }

    //here is code you need to write in onPost
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        if (json != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Borrower_AP.this, json.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                List<YourObject> objs=new ArrayList<>();
                // populate your info from json into objs
                //------your code here for above logic
                //Now create new Message 
                Message msg=new Message();
                msg.obj=objs;
                handler.handleMessage(msg);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```